# How to run multiple lua file at once

Tags: lua

I have 2 file .lua, each file have loops/while

i want execute 2 file lua at once, im trying using dofile, but is not instan
and im not want using dofile inside file 1

im just really want execute all at once with calling file name, its possible?

execute all lua file at once

Comment: Lua doesn't allow running threads in parallel.

Comment: Do you want them to share state? If not, just run them in parallel in separate Lua instances.

Comment: Lua has coroutines. You'll need to adapt your two Lua files to use coroutines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`os.execute("start lua file2.lua")` will start a new Lua instance and run `file2.lua` in parallel with the current file (on Windows).

`dofile` waits for the file to finish executing then runs the code after. Lua has no multithreading (other than coroutines which need you to edit the file itself to support).